# How can I map subclasses of the sqlalchemy declarative_base() class to their tables in a Teradata Database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I have a flask application that relies on an existing Teradata Database to serve up information to and accept input from its users. I am able to successfully make the connection between the application and the Teradata Database, however, I am not able to then define classes that will represent tables already existing in my database.

Currently, I am defining a 'Base' class using sqlalchemy that represents the connection to my database. There is no problem here and I am even able to execute queries using the connection used to build the 'Base' class. However, my problem is in using this 'Base' class to create a subclass 'Users' for my teradata table 'users'. My understanding is that sqlalchemy should allow for me to define a subclass of the superclass 'Base' which will  inherit the metadata from the underlying teradata table that the subclass represents - in this case, my 'users' table. Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import getpass
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData

user = 'user_id_string'
pasw=getpass.getpass()
host = 'host_string'
db_name = 'db_name'

engine = create_engine(f'{host}?user={user}&password={pasw}&logmech=LDAP') 
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(f'DATABASE {db_name}')

md = MetaData(bind=connection, reflect=False, schema='db_name')
md.reflect(only=['users'])

Base = declarative_base(bind=connection, metadata=md)

class Users(Base):
    __table__ = md.tables['db_name.users']
```

This is the error that I receive when constructing the subclass 'Users':

```sh
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class Users->users could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'users'
```

Is there some reason that my subclass 'Users' is not automatically being mapped to the table metadata from the existing teradata table 'users' that I have assigned it to in defining the class? The underlying table already has a primary key set so I don't understand why sqlalchemy is not assuming the existing primary key. Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT: The underlying table DOES NOT have a primary KEY, only a primary INDEX.**

Comment: Are you there's a logical *Primary KEY* on that table or just a physical *Primary INDEX*?

Comment: Thanks you for pointing out that distinction @dnoeth, and yes, I guess my statement was technically incorrect because no, there is not a Primary KEY, only a Primary INDEX. Is there a sqlalchemy requirement that a table must have a Primary KEY?

Comment: See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

**From SQLAlchmey documentation:** (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key)

> The SQLAlchemy ORM, in order to map to a particular table, needs there to be at least one column denoted as a primary key column; multiple-column, i.e. composite, primary keys are of course entirely feasible as well. These columns do not need to be actually known to the database as primary key columns, though it’s a good idea that they are. It’s only necessary that the columns behave as a primary key does, e.g. as a unique and not nullable identifier for a row.
>
> Most ORMs require that objects have some kind of primary key defined because the object in memory must correspond to a uniquely identifiable row in the database table; at the very least, this allows the object can be targeted for UPDATE and DELETE statements which will affect only that object’s row and no other. However, the importance of the primary key goes far beyond that. In SQLAlchemy, all ORM-mapped objects are at all times linked uniquely within a `Session` to their specific database row using a pattern called the identity map, a pattern that’s central to the unit of work system employed by SQLAlchemy, and is also key to the most common (and not-so-common) patterns of ORM usage.
>
> In almost all cases, a table does have a so-called candidate key, which is a column or series of columns that uniquely identify a row. If a table truly doesn’t have this, and has actual fully duplicate rows, the table is not corresponding to first normal form and cannot be mapped. Otherwise, whatever columns comprise the best candidate key can be applied directly to the mapper:
>
> ```
> class SomeClass(Base):
>      __table__ = some_table_with_no_pk
>      __mapper_args__ = {
>          'primary_key':[some_table_with_no_pk.c.uid, some_table_with_no_pk.c.bar]
>      }
> ```
>
> Better yet is when using fully declared table metadata, use the `primary_key=True` flag on those columns:
>
> ```
> class SomeClass(Base):
>      __tablename__ = "some_table_with_no_pk"
>      uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
>      bar = Column(String, primary_key=True)
> ```